# Flex one big feather icon on left-side, title and description on right-side

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I want to create flex style UI that looks like this

[image: Mockup]

what I can do so far is split the UI using col-5 col-2 col-5 from bootstrap, and use flex to create the col-5 UI section (left and right), here's my code

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-5">
                        <div class="d-flex align-items-start">
                            <div class="avatar me-75">
                                <i data-feather="upload" class=avatar-icon></i>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p class="mb-0">Lorem ipsum</p>
                                <p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <div class="d-flex" style="height: 50px;">
                            <div class="vr"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-5">
                        <div class="d-flex align-items-start">
                            <div class="avatar me-75">
                                <i data-feather="user-plus" class=avatar-icon></i>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p class="mb-0">Lorem ipsum</p>
                                <p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the result

[image: My Code]

the results don't match my expectations, is there a class from bootstrap that I haven't added? or is there another way I can get the result like the mockup I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to remove the col-width given to the vertical border and instead add it separately from the css. Also, use the `justify-content-center` class of Bootstrap in the `div` with the `d-flex` class. I hope this is what you are trying to achieve.

```css
.col-6::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-right: 2px dotted #000;
  height: 75px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
              <div class="avatar me-75">
                <i data-feather="upload" class=avatar-icon></i>
              </div>
              <div>
                <p class="mb-0">Lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-6">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
              <div class="avatar me-75">
                <i data-feather="user-plus" class=avatar-icon></i>
              </div>
              <div>
                <p class="mb-0">Lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also created a separate code if you choose to achieve this without using Bootsrap or Flex and instead use the CSS Grid Layout. :)

```css
.card-section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.card-section .card {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 1fr;
  justify-self: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.card-section .card:first-child::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-right: 2px dotted #000;
  height: 100px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
}

.card-section .card .icon-holder {
  background: #000;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-section">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="icon-holder">
      <i class="icon"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="info">
      <h2>
        Title
      </h2>
      <p>
        Description
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="icon-holder">
      <i class="icon"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="info">
      <h2>
        Title
      </h2>
      <p>
        Description
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```